# How should Cypress Cloud runs be canceled when a newer commit is pushed

Tags: cypress, github-actions

We run our Cypress test suite when a commit is pushed. If a newer commit is pushed before the checks have completed, the github action will be cancelled and a new one kicked off.

When this happens cypress cloud doesn't stop the test run and instead goes until timeout.

How are you supposed to handle canceling cypress test runs so that they don't run until the cypress cloud job timeouts after a newer commit has been pushed?

I would have expected the canceled github action to trigger the cypress cloud run to cancel as well but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at the time being (January 2024), it seems this is is not possible.

This is also mentioned in the issues:

- https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/27051
- https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/issues/48

This is due to the runner initializing an outbound connection to cypress cloud and receiving events from there, so if it gets killed there is no interaction from their side to detect that and stop the run.

The suggested [action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action/commit/ddfbba140562b9daf07642320c621aa2aafbb820) is to allow the job to complete so that it reports it is over.

As long as there is no API for Cypress cloud to call and cancel the run, you can't do anything else